# Wrong duration HTML5 audio on mobile browsers, works fine on regular browsers (m4a file)

Tags: html, audio, browser, html5-audio, mobile-browser

I am using Savedeo APIs to get to youtube audio files and trying to play the audio  on a browser.

When I try to play an audio only file (.m4a) on regular browser, everything works fine. But, when I test it on a mobile browser on my iphone (safari and chrome), the audio file's duration is doubled. Basically after the end of the audio, there is a padding added.

Why is this happening? Is there any work around for this. If you need more info, will be happy to provide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with a MP3 with a sample rate of 44100 Hz and a 128kb bitrate.  The solution is to change the sample rate with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i your.mp3 -ar 22050 your_fixed.mp3
```

You can retrieve critical information about an MP3 by using ffprobe:

```
ffprobe your.mp3
```

iTunes also reports the wrong duration when calculating the duration with the actual MP3 file.  That's embarrassing since you would expect iTunes to get something like that correct.  This indicates a bug exists in some library that Apple uses for MP3 duration calculations.